# How to read data from database change them and update database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to read data from database then edit these data with php and update database with these data.

I can get data from database but not able to write them back (I add another query to see if value is changed)

I’ve tried to use phpMyAdmin to see if values are changed but they are stil 
same

```
$POWER = "";
if ($pressed == "1") {
    echo "pressed\n";
    $sql = "SELECT `POWER` FROM `VolleyTest` WHERE ID = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $POWER = $row[0];
        echo "pressed power request $row[0]\n";
    }
    if ($POWER == "ON") {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `VolleyTest` SET `POWER`=\"OFF\" WHERE ID = 1';
        $conn->query($sql);
        echo " POWER ON to OFF\n";
    } else if ($POWER == "OFF") {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `VolleyTest` SET `POWER`=\"ON\" WHERE ID = 1';
        $conn->query($sql);
        echo " POWER OFF to ON\n";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT `POWER` FROM `VolleyTest` WHERE ID = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $POWER = $row[0];
    echo "$row[0]\n";
}
echo $POWER; //. "  ". $pressed . "  " . $_POST['key'];
```

Comment: You don't need to escape your double quotes here. If the queries aren't working, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to escape double quotes inside a single quoted string.

Doing that generates a string like this

```
UPDATE `VolleyTest` SET `POWER`=\"ON\" WHERE ID = 1
```

So this may work

```
$POWER = "";
if ($pressed == "1") {
    echo "pressed\n";
    $sql = "SELECT `POWER` FROM `VolleyTest` WHERE ID = 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        $POWER = $row[0];
        echo "pressed power request $row[0]\n";
    }
    if ($POWER == "ON") {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `VolleyTest` SET `POWER`="OFF" WHERE ID = 1';
        $conn->query($sql);
        echo " POWER ON to OFF\n";
    } else if ($POWER == "OFF") {
        $sql = 'UPDATE `VolleyTest` SET `POWER`="ON" WHERE ID = 1';
        $conn->query($sql);
        echo " POWER OFF to ON\n";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT `POWER` FROM `VolleyTest` WHERE ID = 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $POWER = $row[0];
    echo "$row[0]\n";
}
echo $POWER; //. "  ". $pressed . "  " . $_POST['key'];
```